# Rename variable in C preprocessor

Tags: c, macros, c-preprocessor

I have some existing code that uses an `enum` instead of a function pointer for callbacks. The callback is called using a table: `callback_table[enum]`.

The enums are named with an `enum_ prefix` and the corresponding function is named with a `func_ prefix`.

So, function calls involving callbacks look like this:

```
foo (param, enum_name);
```

While browsing code I have to take the name part and prefix func_ instead of just doing a "Jump to definition".

I would like to have a macro so that my code looks like this:

```
foo (param, f2e(func_name));
```

so that I can keep the existing code unchanged and still be able to do a "Jump to definition".

Is it possible to have such a macro? The simplest solution would be to omit `func_` which means that f2e simple attaches the `enum_ prefix`, but I would prefer a solution where I can still have `func_`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a little round-about, but you could do something like this:

(let's assume, for the sake of this example, that you have three possible enum values `enum_one`, `enum_two`, and `enum_three`).

```
#define enum_func_one enum_one
#define enum_func_two enum_two
#define enum_func_three enum_three

#define f2e(func_name) enum_ ## func_name
```

the drawback (of course) is that you'll need a special #define for each possible value of your enum.

---

**Alternative**

As an alternative, if your only need is to have the function name handy, so you can use your IDE's "jump to definition" feature... you could do something like this:

```
#define f2e(name, func_name)  enum_ ## name
```

then your call would look like this:

```
foo (param, f2e(one, func_one));
```

a little redundant perhaps, but it would accomplish your goal with minimal intrusion into the rest of your code.